# Emberjs get facebook friendlist

Tags: facebook-graph-api, ember.js, ember-data

I'm using Emberjs, Ember Simple Auth, and Torii (for the facebook-oauth2 provider).

I was able to create a Facebook login and logout following this tutorial http://www.programwitherik.com/ember-simple-auth-torii-example-application/

For learning purposes, I'm trying to get my Facebook friendlist using the Ember Simple Auth and Tori not sure how to set up the request in Emberjs. I couldn't find any guidance online..

First I created a custom REST adapter:

```
// adapters/friendlists.js

import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'v2.3/me',
  host: 'https://graph.facebook.com',
  headers: {
    "apiKey": '193080234948021' //api key is manually added. How can I get the api key from Ember Simple Auth/Torii session?
  }
});
```

Next the model:

```
// models/friendlists.js

import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr(),
  list_type: DS.attr()
});
```

...and route:

```
// routes/friendlists.js

import Ember from 'ember';

import AuthenticatedRouteMixin from 'simple-auth/mixins/authenticated-route-mixin';

export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin, {
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('friendlists');
  }
});
```

When I go to `http://localhost:4200/friendlists` I get the following in the console:

> [Report Only] Refused to connect to
>   'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/me/friendlists' because it violates
>   the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self'
>   ws://localhost:35729 ws://0.0.0.0:35729
>   http://0.0.0.0:4200/csp-report".
>
> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/me/friendlists. Invalid HTTP status
>   code 400

When visiting the http request:

> {    "error": {
>         "message": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.",
>         "type": "OAuthException",
>         "code": 2500    }

How can I set an access token on Ember?

Comment: the error message means that you need to use an access token, you can read about those in the facebook docs. that being said, are you sure you want to access "friendlists" and not "friends"? those are 2 different things.

Comment: I'm trying to get friendlists. I'm getting an access token when I log in my app trhough facebook but I could not find any documentation on Ember Simple Auth or Torii how to access that token and use it in my get request.

Comment: still, i am pretty sure you do NOT want to get friendlists, but friends. but whatever, you should not start straight with an article from a blog, start reading here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs

Comment: I'm just getting firendlists for testing purposes but anything could work as long as I find out how to properly return data from the Facebook API into the ember framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Facebook JS API in the following manner:

```
// app/initializers/facebook.js
export function initialize(container, app) {
  app.deferReadiness();
  window.__facebook.then(function() {
    app.advanceReadiness();
  });
}

export default {
  name: 'facebook',
  initialize: initialize
};
```

In index.html:

```
    <script>
      (function(w) {
        var dfd = Ember.RSVP.defer();
        w.__facebook = dfd.promise;
        w.fbAsyncInit = function() {
          FB.init({
            appId      : 'your-app-id',
            xfbml      : true,
            version    : 'v2.3'
          });
          define('FB', [], function() {return FB});
          dfd.resolve(FB);
        };
      })(window);

      (function(d, s, id){
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
```

The trick above is needed in order to delay the app loading until the facebook API is loaded.

```
// adapters/facebook.js (helper function which wraps FB api with a promise)
import Ember from 'ember';

export default function performMethod(path, method, params) {
  method = method || 'get';
  return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    FB.api(path, method, params, function(response) {
      if (!response || response.error) {
        reject(response && response.error);
      } else {
        resolve(response);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

```
// adapters/friend.js
import performMethod from './facebook';
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Adapter.extend({
  findRecord: function() {},
  createRecord: function() {},
  updateRecord: function() {},
  deleteRecord: function() {},
  findAll: function() {
    return performMethod('me', 'get', {fields: 'friends'}).then(function(res) { return res.friends && res.friends.data; });
  },
  query: function() {}
});
```

```
// models/friend.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({  
});
```

Then you use it:

```
// routes/friends.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import AuthenticatedRouteMixin from 'simple-auth/mixins/authenticated-route-mixin';

export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin, {
  model: function() {
    return this.store.findAll('friend');
  }
});
```

Update (28/07/2015): there's an addon I recommend using:
https://github.com/pitchtarget/ember-cli-facebook-js-sdk/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do all of that on the client side I'd use the Facebook JS API instead of the Graph API - just much simpler for that use case.

Comment: Thank you! Ember Simple Auth or Tori might be using the JS api. I will check. I removed my mention of the graph api from my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `?access_token={user_access_token}` in the url, where `{user_access_token}` is a valid User Access Token.